# Rewriting the $.data() function without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wanting to remove the jQuery from the following. As I understand it the $.data() function is used to store data.

I'm a bit stumped on how I could do this.

```
document.querySelector('.sheet').addEventListener('scroll', function() {

    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {

      // do stuff

    }, 250));

});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: `data` actually does a lot internally, it is non trivial to simply replace it.

Comment: @TravisJ While technically true, probably 90% of uses don't depend on anything that isn't done by the `dataset` API.

Comment: @Barmar - I think your number is way off. The dataset API cannot hold objects or functions and therefore is incapable of being used in complex scenarios.

Comment: @TravisJ In my experience here, most people use `.data()` simply to access `data-XXX` attributes, not for those complex scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `dataset` property of HTML elements. The `dataset` property stores the data attributes as a JavaScript object. Using it your code may be written as:

```
document.querySelector('.sheet').addEventListener('scroll', function() {

  clearTimeout(this.dataset.scrollTimer);
  this.dataset.scrollTimer = setTimeout(function() {

    // do stuff

  }, 250);

)};
```